# python:requests.post(url , headers=headers, data=json.dumps(order)) is work,when use C# return error

Tags: python, c#, json, post

In python, it is working:

```
requests.post(url , headers=headers, data=json.dumps(order))
```

When I use C#, then the API return msg:Invalid HTTP Request Input

```cs
string serviceUrl = string.Format("{0}{1}", this._baseUri, uri);
//System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
//serviceUrl = "http://mj.qzdyyy.com/ChsMobilePay/ChsMobilePayApi/v1/GetPayAuthNo";
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceUrl);
byte[] buf = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(data);

myRequest.Method = "POST";
myRequest.ContentLength = buf.Length;
myRequest.KeepAlive = true;
myRequest.Accept = "*/*";  
if (headerDic != null && headerDic.Count != 0)
{
    foreach (var item in headerDic)
    {
        if (item.Key == "ContentType")
        {
            myRequest.ContentType = item.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            myRequest.Headers.Add(item.Key, item.Value );
        }
    }
}

//myRequest.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
myRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
myRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true; 
using (var stream = myRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
}

myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
using (myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse())
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
    //string returnXml = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(reader.ReadToEnd());
    returnXml = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
}
```

I tried to use fillder monitor, but when I use C#, header also have "Content-Type: application/json".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it. In the api,some number should be toString.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).